# Not able to commit data into realtime database of firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to add the data entered by the user into the realtime database, but it stops working and doesn't commit data. The image gets stored in the firebase storage, but data isn't getting saved in realtime and the activity closes and moves back to the previous activity.

This the code in the activity file:

```
pst.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final StorageReference reference = storage.getReference().child("compan")
                    .child(compName.getText().toString())
                    .child(new Date().getTime()+"");
            reference.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Toast.makeText(addPost.this, "Post added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            postModel po = new postModel();
                            po.setPostImg(uri.toString());
                            po.setPostedBy(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());
                            po.setPostDescr(descrip.getText().toString());
                            po.setPostId(new Date().getTime()+"");

                            database.getReference().child("Company").child(compName.getText().toString())
                                    .push()
                                    .setValue(po).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                    Toast.makeText(addPost.this, "Post added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

On trying a lot I got the following error in the logcat:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sGbk.png)

Am I missing something? I don't know what to do as the storage and authentication works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the `database` object, it seems it hasn't been initialized before using:

```
database = ... // initialize somehow
database.getReference().child("Company").child(compName.getText().toString())
...
```

Comment: It seems the error is on the `database` object, I've edited my answer, please check.

Comment: Yes I had missed the database..... it works now